# python logging printing empty lines message for print

Tags: python, logging, gunicorn, falcon

We are trying to introducing python **logging** in out existing python project.

As we already have lot more **print** statement in code, we decided to redirect all print logs to logging file using below statement.

```
import logging, sys
import os
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(pathname)s - %(funcName)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
log_path = '/logs/server.log'
handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename=log_path, when='midnight')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.addHandler(handler)
sys.stderr.write = log.error
sys.stdout.write = log.info
```

However, it printing two lines with second as empty logs.

```
2020-09-21 09:03:05,978 - utils.py - logger - INFO - <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
2020-09-21 09:03:05,978 - utils.py - logger - INFO -

2020-09-21 09:03:05,978 - utils.py - logger - INFO - 1600693385   Mon Sep 21 09:03:05 2020        19882 Registering functions
2020-09-21 09:03:05,978 - utils.py - logger - INFO -
```

It is working for logging function like **info, error**. it only giving issue for **print**.

It would be great help if someone know cause of it.

In additional detail, we are using **gunicorn** as server and **falcon** as rest framework.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879206/python-logging-stdout-but-getting-second-blank-line-on-each-entry

Answer (score 1):

You should not modify the write functions of stdout and stderr but add a stream handler for info and for error (one on stdout and the other one on stderr)

You can find an example on SO here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31459386/14306518