# logger to a file (via sys.stdout) adds extra empty lines

Tags: python, logging, stdout

EDIT: probably the same issue as [python - logging stdout, but getting second blank line on each entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879206/python-logging-stdout-but-getting-second-blank-line-on-each-entry)

I was playing with `logger` when I found this strange (?) behavior.

- In define a class which redefines  `sys.stdout` as being `self` and which has a `write` method
- the `write`  method calls `logger` to write in a file.

The following scripts adds two empty lines between the two `print`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import logging
import sys

# Define a logger which writes in a file
logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler('mylog.log')
logger.addHandler(handler)

class MyStd:
    def __init__(self):
        # Redefine 'sys.stdout' as being 'self'
        sys.stdout = self

    def write(self, text):
        # Intercept the 'print' and use the logger instead.
        logger.warning(text.rstrip())


_ = MyStd()

print("a")
print("b")
```

If I replace `self.logger.warning(text)` by `self.logger.warning(text.replace("\n", ""))` I get only one extra empty line.

Questions :

- Where do the empty lines come from ?
- How to remove them ?

Comment: Change write to do `logger.warning(repr(text))` then you'll see what's happening. On my system, I get `'a'<linebreak>'\n'<linebreak>'b'<linebreak>'\n'<linebreak>` in mylog.log

Comment: Your write method is called 4 times: `'a', '\n', 'b', '\n'`. When calling it with only `'\n'`, you strip it to an empty string `''`, but logging would still generate a line.

Comment: Ok. I see. So "print" not only adds a "\n" (I was already aware of that), but in fact it calls twice "sys.stdout.write": once with the text and once with the extra "\n" ?